# Is there a way to rank multiple columns in power query?

Tags: ranking, powerquery, m

I am setting up a query where I need to rank multiple columns. I was able to sort the first column in descending order and inserted an index column. However, I am not able to rank the other columns.

I have included an example below:
Table to show agent performance

```
Agent  | surveys | rank  | outcalls |total calls |outcalls/total calls |rank
Dallas |  80%    |   1   |    50    |  80        |      62.5%          | ?
May    |  75%    |   2   |    90    |  100       |      90.0%          | ?
Summer |  60%    |   3   |    60    |  75        |      80.0%          | ?
```

So  basically from the example above, I was able to add an index column that ranked the surveys. How can I rank the outcalls/total calls column while still maintaining the rank in the other columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, a simple approach would be to sort on `outcalls/total calls`, add another index column, and then sort the first `rank` column if you want to revert back to your starting order.

Comment: @Vava Can you be more descriptive? It definitely worked when I tried it, assuming you want the rank to be `3,1,2`.

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry it did. I just needed to reorder my columns in the format I needed. Thanks again (insert hi-five emoji)